# How do I implement methods using pass parameters by reference and Implement method overloading?

Tags: c#, console

Need to find the sum of the digits of a four-digit number (the remainder of the division
whole numbers)

I just don't understand how to implement method overloading and method passing by reference at the same time. Can you tell me something?`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have example code?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write the code yourself and ask questions if you have any problems. But I will answer this as an exception...

`Method overloading` allows you to define multiple methods with the same name but different parameter.

```
public static int sumOfDigits(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}


public static void sumOfDigits(ref int num)
{
    num = sumOfDigits(num);
}
```

Now you can call the overloaded function with a reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int number = 3334;
     int sum = sumOfDigits(number);
     Console.WriteLine($"Sum of digits: {sum}");

     sumOfDigits(ref number);
     Console.WriteLine($"Sum of digits by method overloading and passing by reference: {number}");
}
```

See these links for more information:

[C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

[Method Overloading](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_method_overloading.php)